# How to install AWS SDK for Android and should I?

Tags: android, python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I want to release an Android app for AWS management with user filled credentials and i want to setup AWS SDK (assuming it works like boto3 for python and Java SDK). How to do that? I found a tutorial for installation but it seems that is limited only to current (my) account if i did understand it. I want to manage whatever profile is given with a user login and credentials fields. I am starting to feel that this is not possible. I have quite a lot hands on with AWS and boto3 and i want to implement something similar with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly get started with AWS Mobile through AWS Mobile Hub & SDK. The Getting Started page is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html. This page provides information to enabling AWS with your app and connecting to the cloud backend.

For authentication, you can refer to the User SignIn docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html. Here, we provide AWS Auth SDK which has a built-in SignIn UI with Email/Password Login, Facebook and Google Login in Native views.

If you want a web hosted UI, you can refer to Amazon Cognito Auth: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

Comment: i found all those pages and i was left with the impression that Mobile Hub is Account specific. If i make an app with it and let's say you download it from google play store. Can you manage YOUR account? Or it is limited to mine only?

Comment: also i don't see any EC2 functionality. Android hub allow for very few things. There is no ec2 client?

Comment: Currently we support API Gateway and Lambda for server-less cloud back-end. The Hub doesn't support EC2. However, you can configure the necessary EC2 instances and use the AWS EC2 SDK to connect to it.

Comment: I was focusing on Instance creation/ASG/Load balancing. So this will be supported in future?

Comment: You can refer to AWS EC@ SDK here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/tree/master/aws-android-sdk-ec2 and for load balancing, here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/tree/master/aws-android-sdk-elb. Please feel free to open an issue in github when you face a roadblock in using the APIs: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues

Comment: Is there anything additional prerequisite outside of adding the library? Cant seem to find any documentation thats is not for java sdk.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: All the links which you shared in answer redirect to Amplify framework documentation. Why AWS is pushing to use amplify? I have asked a separate question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973171/android-amplify-uploading-downloading-file-to-from-aws-s3-using-amplify for clarification. Can you please answer there?